# Cloth is going through other Cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

I modeled a shirt and shorts and put them on my character. My character has a collision and they both have cloth simulations. The Shirt is slightly bigger than the pants so that it can rest on top of the pants. I pinned the top of the pants so that they wouldn't fall off but now whenever I play the cloth animation, the shirt goes through the pants and the pin. Do I have to add something to the cloth to make it so that one mesh doesn't go through another or is there something wrong with the pinning?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a collision to the pants as well, so the shirt knows, that it should collide with the pants and not go through. That should do the trick.

All the best Marco